# colorbox dynamic url

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Colorbox wont accept dynamic url it appears?, not sure why this wont work.. (selector is image with 'scr' that has dynamic generated value (sku). Any ideas?

on doc ready.;

```
$('.product-selected .column-2 img').css('cursor', 'pointer').colorbox({
                  href : '/loading-designer?sku='+$(this).attr('alt')+'&type=direct'
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to control for the value of 'this' (the execution context).  In this situation, `$(this).attr('alt')` is probably `undefined` because `this` probably refers to the window object.

To make sure that `this` refers to your img element, you could do something like this:

```
$('.product-selected .column-2 img').css('cursor', 'pointer').colorbox({
    href : function(){ 
           return '/loading-designer?sku='+$(this).attr('alt')+'&type=direct';
    }
});
```

Or this:

```
$('.product-selected .column-2 img').css('cursor', 'pointer').each(function(){
    $(this).colorbox({href : '/loading-designer?sku='+$(this).attr('alt')+'&type=direct'});
});
```